# Get a single specific value from json

Tags: ios, json, key-value, weather-api

As you might expect, i'm fairly new to obj-C, and i'm constantly trying to build knowledge and experience. But i'm still struggling with  a lot of concepts, and that includes JSON data 'catching'.
I've seen many tutorials and guides but i just can't translate them into what i need. Most of the time they layout data in  arrays or get multiple values, and (of course) use different variables, which makes everything confusing and unclear to me, even though this should be stupidly simple.

I'm trying to do something very simple : 
**Get a single value from the open weather API, the temperature.**

I'll show you my code  which, according to my disgraceful knowledge, should be perfect, but apparently it doesn't work :D

```
@implementation HomeViewController
{

    NSMutableArray *tableData;
    NSDictionary *jsonDict;
    NSMutableString *title;
}
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSError *error;


    //I create my data array and the string i'll store my value later on
    tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    title = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

   // Creating the link for the json api so it fits coordinates ; this works but i edited the locations out to clear the code
    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=%.05f&lon=%.05f", _annotation.coordinate.latitude, _annotation.coordinate.longitude];

    // I go online and catch the data of the url stored in S
    NSData *jSonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:s]];

    // This is a dictionary where all my data is stored from jsonData, keys and values all the way
    jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jSonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    // I use the string created previously and assign it the value stored in that dictionary, in the TEMP 'folder', right under MAIN.

    title = [[jsonDict objectForKey:@"main"]objectForKey:@"main.temp"];

     // I assign that title to a label so it appears in my view.
     self.tempLabel.text = title;
    ...
    }
```

There you go. I'm probably missing something very simple but i've been stuck on this and even if i feel I know what i'm doing, i'm probably missing something. So it'd be great if with the answer you give me, you could also tell me what I did wrong :D

Thank you very much for your support and knowledge. This community is amazing :)

Comment: Put an `NSLog( @"%@", jsonDict );` after the `NSJSONSerialization` line, and add the output to your question.  That will make it much easier for people to help you with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Put a breakpoint after assigning value to `jsonDict` and use

`po jsonDict`

in the console to print out what you are getting. Then, adjust the code that extracts the value. And use modern Objective-C syntax for it.

#### Example

```
title = jsonDict[@"main"][@"temp"];
```

#### Note

`po` is a debugger command that will print out the contents of an object. If you need to print out the contents of a primitive, use `p` instead.

Comment: If you could tell me what a 'po' is i'd gladly  try it :D

Comment: `po` is a debugger command that will print out the contents of an object.

Answer (score 0):

This should set you right:

`title = [[jsonDict objectForKey:@"main"]objectForKey:@"temp"];`

To explain the issue, it seems you were referring to `temp` using a combination of dot syntax in the key.

**EDIT: In response to your error:**

That error appears when you're trying to find the length of a string on a value that is not of NSString type.  Looks like `temp` is being returned as a number.  So, to do what it looks like you're trying to do, you'll wanna convert `[[jsonDict objectForKey:@"main"]objectForKey:@"temp"]` to an NSString:

`NSNumber *temp = [[jsonDict objectForKey:@"main"]objectForKey:@"temp"];
NSString *tempString = [temp stringValue];`

OR

`NSString *temp = [[[jsonDict objectForKey:@"main"]objectForKey:@"temp"] stringValue];`

That will allow you to get the `length`: `temp.length`

**EDIT: Unless you're trying to get the length of the array of weather data...in which case i'd like to see more of that code

Comment: I also tried this but it makes the app crash when i reach the page where i'm supposed to see the temperature ; this is the error i'm getting : **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x19e3ad30'**

Answer (score 0):

My guess is

```
 jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jSonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

is trying to create an nsdictionary, but it the results are coming back as an array. Try this:

```
NSError *e = nil;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: jsonDict options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

if (!jsonArray) {
  NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", e);
} else {
   for(NSDictionary *item in jsonArray) {
      NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
   }
}
```